# How to create a floor function with a "step" argument

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I would like to create a function floor(number, step), which acts like :

```
floor(0, 1) = 0
floor(1, 1) = 1
floor(1, 2) = 0
floor(5, 2) = 4
floor(.8, .25) = .75
```

What is the better way to do something like that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the step always going to be a power of two, as in your examples?

Comment: Nope. Just any number :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like `floor( val / step ) * step`

Answer (score 2):

what you want is basically the same as

`step * (x // step)`

isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the code below ought to do the job.

```
def stepped_floor (n, step=1):
    return n - (n % step)
```